# How to warn me if a function throws an exception but is not documented as such?

Tags: php, doxygen

Say I have the following php file:

```
<?php

main();

function main() {
  echo shouldNotThrowException();
}

/**
 * Dummy function
 *
 * @param $x
 *   A positive int
 *
 * @return
 *   Returns $x if positive
 *
 * @throws
 *   Exception
 */
function throwsException($x) {
  if ($x < 0) {
    throw Exception(__FUNCTION__ . ': x cannot be negative.');
  }
  return $x;
}

/**
 * Dummy function
 *
 * @return
 *   Returns 4.
 */
function shouldNotThrowException() {
  return throwsException(4);
}
```

Can I get Doxygen or some other tool to warn me that `shouldNotThrowException()` throws an Exception but is not documented as such?

My reasoning is that, sometimes in complex code bases, with many functions, we sometimes can forget to catch an Exception in the appropriate place. For example, Drupal hooks should never throw Exceptions, but rather log them appropriately using `drupal_set_message()` or `watchdog()`. However, it is possible that some programmers may call functions in Drupal hooks which themselves throw Exceptions, without catching and displaying/logging them appropriately. I want my continuous integration server to run doxygen and warn me of such cases.

Comment: At least theoretically this is possible, but you can never automatically detect if there is indeed a chance an exception will be thrown. For instance in your example `shouldNotThrowException` will never throw an exception since `$x` is `4` and thus positive. This algebraic manipulation cannot be done by a compiler.

Comment: Even though `shouldNotThrowException` will never throw an exception in this case, the idea is that it calls a function which throws an exception, yet it itself is not documented as throwing an exception, therefore users of the API might be under the false impression that it does not throw an exception. I opened an issue on the pdepend metrics tool requesting such a feature: https://github.com/pdepend/pdepend/issues/168

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [exception handler](http://php.net/function.set-exception-handler) and catch those cases, but the script execution would still be aborted because, well, an exception was encountered that wasn't catched. This is the desired behavior.